# How can I make my nav bar a little fatter with Bootstrap to fit a logo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My nav bar dose not expand irrespective to the image.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.thecoyotebandits.com/">
    <img class="brand" src="http://static.tumblr.com/vs9to3z/Ts6n7uu17/logo.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup (HTML), find the class(es) that dictate the navbar's height, and add a custom class like so:

```
<div class="existing-class tall">Content</div>
```

with this in a `custom.css` doc:

```
.tall{height:120px} /* experiment with the height depending on your image */
```

There are other ways to do the same (override bootstrap's class in either your custom.css doc or right in the bootstrap.css, add the css inline, or add the css into your HTML doc's `head`) but the above is really a best practice and the easiest to manage long-term.

Also, now that I'm done teaching and preaching, in this case you'll add the class to `navbar-brand` as I've done here: http://www.bootply.com/ZFrMg9asaI

```
<a class="navbar-brand tall" href="http://www.thecoyotebandits.com/">
```